# Finding out if browser supports cookies on the server side

Tags: java, http, cookies

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Is it possible to know if browser has cookies enabled on the very first access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865838/is-it-possible-to-know-if-browser-has-cookies-enabled-on-the-very-first-access)

I am using HttpOnly cookies which are not accessible using javascript on the client side.
I wish to find out if the browser supports cookies in the first request only.
Is it possible to get this information from http request?

Comment: What technologie do you use on the server?

Comment: Do you use servlets, JSP, JAX-RS, JAX-WS, ...?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865838/is-it-possible-to-know-if-browser-has-cookies-enabled-on-the-very-first-access

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to decide from the server side with one request whether the actual client supports HTTP cookie saving or not, then the answer is unfortunately no, you cannot.

Although you can send the HTTP cookie in the first request and check in the second that cookie has been saved or not. But be aware of that this will not guarantee that the expiry setting of the cookie has been accepted or not.

So for example you want to store an HTTP cookie for a year, but the client accepts only session cookies. In this case in the second request you'll see your cookie, but if the user closes his browser there will be no cookie in the next requests.

Answer (score 3):

You need two requests from the browser one to set a test cookie and other to read it, although the second request could be performed automatically if the first one returns a redirection.

Comment: but i want to know it in the very first access.
got the answer. Its not possible

Comment: NO way to figure out in the first request, the only thing you could do is to suppose that the client accepts cookies based on the user agent, so you could discard certain clients like crawlers, but this does not guarantees anything.

Answer (score 0):

At the very first initial contact (like user never visited your site before or cleared all cookies) - no. But if you send a cookie with a first response then you analyse if the cookie came back with the next request. If user visited your site recently and cookies are enabled then you can detect it with a first request in this session.

Generally speaking, the next request is any request - it could be an image or css file referred by the content loaded with the first request.